# how to add strings and numbers into a list from a csv file?

Tags: r, csv

I have a list like the following in R:

```
data1<-list("A" = 1, "B" = 2, "C" = 3,"D" = 4)
```

and when I print data1 I have:

```
$A
[1] 1

$B
[1] 2

$C
[1] 3

$D
[1] 4
```

I have a csv file with the values:

```
alt1,alt2,alt3,alt4
appear,certain,dance,example
apply,danger,chance,excellent
```

where alt1,alt2,... are the headers of the csv.file

I would like to extract the second row from my csv file so that I could get something like data1, I have done the following:

```
    getData=read.csv("test.csv",header=TRUE)
    q<-getData[2,]
    print(q)
    anylist<-list()
    anylist[[q[1]]]<-1
    anylist[[q[2]]]<-2
    anylist[[q[3]]]<-3
    anylist[[q[4]]]<-4
    print(anylist)
```

because I need that anylist to have the same structure like data1, I mean if I will have to write directly it would be:

```
anylist<-list("apply" = 1, "danger" = 2, "chance" = 3,"excellent" = 4)
```

so when I print anylist I want to print:

```
$apply
[1] 1

$danger
[1] 2

$chance
[1] 3

$excellent
[1] 4
```

but I got the error:

```
Error in anylist[[q[1]]] <- 1 : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following quick function will take a row of data, determine the order, and associate order and name, outputting a list. I believe this is what you wanted, right? If you wanted to do this for many rows, simply use an `apply` statement, with `MARGIN=1`, and you will get a list of lists. Is this what you were looking for?

```
getNames=function(row){
    retList=as.list(order(row))
    names(retList) = as.character(sort(row))
    return(retList)
}
```

...here's a quick validation.

```
test=c("apply", "danger", "chance", "excellent")

getNames(test)
$apply
[1] 1

$chance
[1] 3

$danger
[1] 2

$excellent
[1] 4

test2=c('alt1','alt2','alt3','alt4')
getNames(test2)

$alt1
[1] 1

$alt2
[1] 2

$alt3
[1] 3

$alt4
[1] 4
```

Comment: I do not need to order the rows, also with the csv example I got list(structure(1:4, .Names = c("2", "2", "2", "2"))), something that I do not want. I have updated the question if you want to take a look

Comment: So the `1:4` you assign the list elements named based on the row from the csv file aren't the vector indices? I'm sorry for the confusion. I do see some errors in my answer, and have edited the answer to hopefully suit your needs.

Comment: thanks, but when you apply your data that is in test is different from the one that I have in the csv file, that is why in the answer it prints only values of 2,2,2,2

Comment: I have no idea why you are getting values of 2 on your data. I thought it could be treating the strings as factors, but I tried that, and the function still worked (in its currently edited form). Sorry I wasn't able to help. I'll let somebody else with a bit more expertise provide a clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha!

```
getData=read.csv("test.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
q<-getData[2,]
n<-as.list(c(1:4))
names(n)<-q
```